# Django static file not changing my website when I make edits

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and web page design but I am having an issue I can't seem to find an answer for anywhere.
I want to tweak the look of my web page a bit but for some reason when I go into the static file to change e.g. the RGB value for header colour it doesn't change to the new colour entered despite me saving the file and resetting the server. I even tried deleting the static file entirely and it made no change to my web page. It seems to me that somehow it has saved the data from the original static file I made and no matter what I change the file to it won't impact the page in any way.
Please give me any suggestions for things that you think could be causing this issue to happen, Thanks.

```
{% load static %}
```

Note; if I get rid of the above line from my code the webpage totally breaks and if I get rid of the below line the webpage e.g. has no header colour (it doesn't even use the data I originally entered into the static file)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
```

CSS file:

```
.page-header {
    background-color: #6EC1DF;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 36pt;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.date {
    color: #828282;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.save {
    float: right;
}

.post-form textarea, .post-form input {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-menu, .top-menu:hover, .top-menu:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.post {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.post h2 a, .post h2 a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}

.comment {
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

Main web page file:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Blog</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                <p class="top-menu">Hello {{ user.username }} <small>(<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>)</small></p>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
            <h1><a href="/">My Blog</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.12.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '9xv1u3^ux==n=eq!mozt4!=n=^$%p89u%lwhb+i*7c3@t6zlk*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-uk'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

[screen shot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKlRV.png)

Comment: can you please run the command `python manage.py collectstatic` and check again

Comment: i just tried this, it still doesnt work :(

Comment: can you please give a screenshot of your site which is loading in the browser. Also, paste your settings.py here too

Comment: I've put both in the original question hope they help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two possibilities:

1- you are not changing the CSS correctly, post your code, please.

2- your browser is caching statics but from what you told it's not, just try ctr + f5 or shift + f5 maybe something happens.

Comment: 1. I've posted code on the original question 2. didn't seem to do anything

Comment: go to the inspect element of the browser then change the blog.css file and check sources to see if blog.css file has changed too

Comment: When I make the change in the elements tab and then move over to sources the change is still there but when I refresh the browsers it goes back to how it was before. If that is what you meant for me to do?

Comment: no no don't change the element in the inspector, see if after you change it in source code and reloading the page it gets changed in the inspector source tab too

Comment: oh no sorry, that doesn't work either though, no changes I make to the source code of the static file impact the website in any way even when I check the inspector after I save the change

Comment: ok, what is your browser?? are you testing on local? try to change the CSS file so that it must be visible on the browser (like changing the background of the body to blue), then open the page on another browser or just open it with incognito see if page changes? or even CSS file loaded in DOM is changed?

Comment: Ok, I just opened my webpage in another browser and in that browser, it displays the page with my changes (In the new CSS file I changed the header to blue) but it is still orange in chrome even when I fully exit Chrome and re-load it. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I put your HTML/CSS in a codepen and it works fine, I think the reason you get no changes is that you have linked bootstrap in your header and the tag page-header is overwritten there, try putting your blog.css link in the header on top of other links and see what happens.

Comment: this fixed it thank you! weird how it worked in incognito and in other browsers but I had to move that link to make it work in my regular chrome

Comment: I don't know why but ctrl+f5 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have the CSS file at `/home/myusername/myproject/static/css/your_css.css`, go visit `http://pxb945.eu.pythonanywhere.com//static/css/your_css.css` and see if the files are same. If it is not, then you have to run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it will reflect the changes

Also, If your web app running through cloudflare. They have caching that is probably what is causing the effects you're seeing.

Comment: the CSS file in my directory matches the one at http://pxb945.eu.pythonanywhere.com//static/css/your_css.css, however, neither of these files are the static files my page seems to be using. This is still the case after using that collectstatic command

Comment: also im not using cloud flare